# SharePoint 2013 CQWP with Two Grouping Levels

Tags: 2013, content-query-web-part, grouping

Is it possible to have a custom Content Query Web Part that has two grouping levels?

```
Group 1
   Group A
     Item 1
     Item 2
   Group B
     Item 3
     Item 4
Group 2
   Group A
     Item 5
     Item 6
   Group B
     Item 7
     Item 8
```

Comment: Try using Content By Search web part and modify the display templates.

Answer (score 0):

It is, with calculated fields.

For example: I want to group a list by year, then by month.

I can achieve this by going to my list settings, creating a calculated column, and then creating a formula that groups first by year, then by month.

Finally, I simply edit my Content Query Web Part, and select that new list item under Presentation > Grouping.

I hope this helps!

[image: Calculated Column]

[image: CQWP Configuration]

Answer (score 0):

to make CQWP  to have sub grouping we need to modify contentquerymain.xsl file which is difficult , instead of this we can use crossList data view web part which does the same job with more features. we can have 2 or more levels of sub groups